# Reliable Multicast Programming (PGM) on Windows

Tags: streaming, multicast, video-streaming, ip-routing, realtime

I want to use the Reliable Multicast Programming (PGM) protocol on Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I know Windows support it. However, it seems that I need network devices (routers and switches) that support that protocol in order to use it on the network. I also would like to use that protocol over the Internet (VPN?).

Could you give me any advice on what hardware do I need as well as ideas on how to use that over the Internet (I want to connect different offices)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Cisco and Juniper people are on the author list for the stated RFC, the hardware for it exists out there.

Cisco [looks to support it on their 7x00 series of switches](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2s/release/notes/122Srn.html#wp1268706).

Connecting it over the Internet to different offices will require either direct connections between the offices or a VPN. Multicast is generally not passed over normal Internet connections, so you have to own (physically or virtually) the entire network path.

Comment: There is open source implementation of the protocol - OpenPMG that supports a wide range of operating systems and architectures. UDP encapsulation is also supported.

http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/

Comment: @Coder That makes it a lot cheaper, though it means your end-point routing infrastructure needs to be based on a *nix software router.